# Access VBA put a form element name as an argument

Tags: vba, ms-access

Let's see if anyone knows how to solve this problem:

I have a form with several elements: Some of them are textboxes called A1, A2, A3, A4...

Now, their AfterUpdate SubProcedure is extremely long but barely similar for each of them: A1_AfterUpdate, A2_AfterUpdate, A3_AfterUpdate...etc... are very similar but for the names of the textboxes they change.

My idea was to gather all that was equal in a subprocedure defined this way:

```
Private Sub Update(Box As String, Menu As Boolean)
   If Menu=True{ 
   Me!Box.Text = "This is the text that is going to change"
   }
End Sub
```

So, the only thing I must do is to call it this way, for instance:

```
Update(A1, True)
```

But it doesn't seems to work. Any idea on how to reach this objective?

Comment: `Box as TextBox` not as `string`. You should concider public generic function or Class with eventhanders

Comment: there are no `{` in VBA. Your syntax does not look like VBA at all. It's `If` `Then` `End If`

Answer (score 2):

Add a class module - I've called it `clsTextBoxEvents`.

Add this code to the class:

```
Public WithEvents txt As Access.TextBox

Private Sub txt_AfterUpdate()
    MsgBox txt.Name & " has been updated."
End Sub
```

In your form module add this code:

```
Public MyTextBoxes As New Collection

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim txtBoxEvent As clsTextBoxEvents

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
            Set txtBoxEvent = New clsTextBoxEvents
            Set txtBoxEvent.txt = ctl
            txtBoxEvent.txt.AfterUpdate = "[Event Procedure]"
            MyTextBoxes.Add txtBoxEvent
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

The `MyTextBoxes` declaration must be at the very top of the module.

This just adds the `AfterUpdate` event to all textboxes on the form.  You'll probably want to refine that a bit to textboxes with specific text in the name, or controls that are in a specific frame on the form.

Comment: Impressive, but seems complex. Did you ever actually use such construct ? A use case perhaps ? Thx

Comment: I don't understand the role of the MyTextBoxes collection. By reading the code with my knowledge it seems that nothing is done with it. What do I miss ?

Comment: The `MyTextBoxes` collection should be `Private` really as it's only used in the form.  The collection is used to store each instance of the class - one for each textbox.  Without the `MyTextBoxes.Add txtBoxEvent` at the end none of the events fire.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I have to say I've not used such a construct in Access as I'd usually use a `Continuous Form` set up if I had lots of controls doing the same thing, but that would need changes to the tables as well.  I've used similar code in Excel when creating controls at runtime.  Now you've got me trying to think of a useful use case and all I'm thinking is "_are very similar but for the names of the textboxes they change_" from the OPs question.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I use this type of construct all the time for validating or restricting input - i.e. a group of TextBoxes that only accept numeric input. If you think this is "complex", you haven't seen the code-behind with 5 or 10 duplicate copies of a `KeyPress` event. This is much cleaner.

Comment: @Comintern  I've used it in Excel to validate form entries on the `Change` event.  Build a class that looks at the `Tag` property of an Excel form control - only allow 2 decimal places, must have 2 decimal places and a % sign, convert each word to Proper, etc.  E.g. `9;CCUR;REQD` would mean _place contents in column 9 of worksheet_, _Currency_, _Required Field_.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function instead of a sub:

```
Private Function UpdateCtl(Menu As Boolean)
   If Menu Then 
       activecontrol = "This is the text that is going to change"
   End If
End Sub
```

then you can call it directly from the control's AfterUpdate property: `=UpdateCtl(True)`.
Simple and fast

Comment: Please consider adding a little explanation to your answer. Code-only answers automatically get flagged as low quality, yours is currently [in review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21485307)